# ASP Download counter

Tags: asp.net

I will make upload my application today to my homepage and wanna to have a simple download counter.

Asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this XML based ASP.NET "hit counter" for you:

http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Hit-Counter-for-ASPNET.aspx

Simply put this (basically) on an onClick function.

Hopefully, this will help.